# Read Boxplot Parameters from Table in Latex

Tags: latex, boxplot, tikz

I found this code to plotting group Boxplot in Latex, if I want to read Boxplot parameters values such as median, whiskers values from table , how can I modify this code in order to read parameters value instead of absolute data

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
boxplot/draw direction=y,
cycle list={{red},{blue}},
boxplot={
        draw position={1/3 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/2) + 1/3*mod(\plotnumofactualtype,2)},
        box extend=0.3
},
xtick={0,1,2,...,10},
x tick label as interval,
xticklabels={ {dataset 1},{dataset 2},{dataset 3} },
        x tick label style={
                text width=2.5cm,
                align=center
        },
]

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.764\\
3.938\\
2.075\\
1.493\\
1.285\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.175\\
2.813\\
2.006\\
3.893\\
2.012\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.621\\
3.659\\
6.357\\
2.851\\
1.416\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.280\\
1.482\\
1.787\\
2.326\\
1.795\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.778\\
2.388\\
1.016\\
1.328\\
1.151\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.028\\
1.571\\
4.090\\
3.875\\
1.890\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```